# Forcing chromecast to a specific app

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

This question can be asked a couple of different ways, but so far it does not seem obvious how or whether it will be possible to specify a single app that a Chromecast device should be locked to - or put another way, can you whitelist the app (not whitelisting the app ID for development) that the Chromecast will run ?

I want to have my chromecast only run 1 specific predefined app, being driven from a (potentially whitelisted host) single host - does anyone know how to do that yet ?

Has or will Google give any guidance on whether this would be a supported use-case (only allow X app on Y host to take over this Chromecast) ?

Comment: Take a look at this feature request https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=62.  It seems similar to your request.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean controlling the list of "whitelisted" apps yourself, no, it is not a supported use case.  Why would you need such feature?

Comment: This would be good for digital signage.  We currently use raspberry pi's for this.

Comment: Lets say we have this feature and you restrict a certain collection of devices to only one app. Still, even in this case, user needs to start that app manually, i.e. no app starts on its own, even if there is only one app enabled on the device. Would this be what you want as a solution for digital signage? I presume (I might be wrong) that you want that single app to start automatically when the device boots up, which is a different thing, which doesn't need the app restriction feature.

Comment: Yes, it would need to start a single app automatically and not allow any other apps to run.  That's the way I interpreted the OP's statement "I want to have my chromecast only run 1 specific predefined app".  This would have to be configured during setup and only editable after a factory reset.

Comment: This is exactly the use case, and yes the user would have to start the controlling app manually, but wouldn't have to worry about someone else on the network taking over the chromecast.

Comment: So to iterate my earlier comment, locking down a collection of chromecast devices to run only one app is not a supported use case.